# Carousel not working..?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

**my carousel is not working when tried to implement in a php page..??**
**But its working fine in bootsnipp. Below is the link for the snippet code.**

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/3qPxB

**below is the package details ive included.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**below is the my html code**

```
      <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- Carousel
        ================================================== -->
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">        
            <div class="carousel-inner">           
                <div class="item active"> 
                    <a href="#"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x400/" alt="Slide1"></a>
                    <div class="caption">
                      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item"> 
                    <a href="#"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x400/" alt="Slide2"></a>
                    <div class="caption">
                      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
                    </div>                                                           
                 </div>  
                <div class="item"> 
                    <a href="#"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x400/" alt="Slide3"></a>
                    <div class="caption">
                      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
                    </div>                        
                </div>                                                                                   
            </div>
             <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>                                                                 
        </div><!-- End Carousel -->  
    </div>
</div>
```

**Below is my css**

```
    body { padding-top: 50px; }

 .carousel-indicators {
bottom:-40px;
left:0;
width:100%;
background:#ccc;
padding: 6px 0px;
margin-left:0;
border-top:2px solid #fff;
  }
   .carousel-indicators li {
width:12px;
height:12px;    
background:#fff;
border-color:#fff;

 }
 .carousel-indicators .active {
width:14px;
height:14px;
background:#428bca;
border-color:#428bca;
 }
   .carousel-inner .thumbnail {
margin-bottom:0;
border-bottom-left-radius:0;
border-bottom-right-radius:0;
   }
  .carousel-inner .caption {
background:#ddd;
padding: 10px;
}
```

**Below is my script code**

```
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval:   1000
});
```

**if ive missed any library link please notify me thanks in advance**

Comment: You haven't included the bootstrap JS library. You've only included the CSS.

Comment: Add bootstrap.min.js file.

Comment: I don't see you including `"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"` Include it after the jquery script

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan..now ive included bootstrap js also but its not working..

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstra‌​p.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: As I said Pradeep, Include the bootstrap.js script after the jquery.js script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this working snppet

```js
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval:   1000
});
```

```css
body { padding-top: 50px; }

 .carousel-indicators {
bottom:-40px;
left:0;
width:100%;
background:#ccc;
padding: 6px 0px;
margin-left:0;
border-top:2px solid #fff;
  }
   .carousel-indicators li {
width:12px;
height:12px;    
background:#fff;
border-color:#fff;

 }
 .carousel-indicators .active {
width:14px;
height:14px;
background:#428bca;
border-color:#428bca;
 }
   .carousel-inner .thumbnail {
margin-bottom:0;
border-bottom-left-radius:0;
border-bottom-right-radius:0;
   }
  .carousel-inner .caption {
background:#ddd;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- Carousel
            ================================================== -->
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">        
                <div class="carousel-inner">           
                    <div class="item active"> 
                     <a href="#"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x400/" alt="Slide1"></a>
                        <div class="caption">
                          <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item"> 
                     <a href="#"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x400/" alt="Slide2"></a>
                        <div class="caption">
                          <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
                        </div>                                                           
                     </div>  
                    <div class="item"> 
                     <a href="#"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x400/" alt="Slide3"></a>
                        <div class="caption">
                          <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>                                                                                   
                </div>
                 <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  </ol>                                                                 
            </div><!-- End Carousel -->  
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Greetings!

Comment: Have fun @Pradeep..:)

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. load jquery before bootstrap.min.js

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstra‌​p.min.js"></script>